# How to show data one word one cell rather than one character one cell in csv_file?

Tags: python, csv

I practice to crawl the data from the website. 
Here is the website: https://delicious-fruit.com/ratings/full.php?q=ALL

My main target is to collect game name, difficulty, rating, number of rating, and then save file with csv. The format is one word one cell, four words one wrap.

When I tried to save file, there was a problem happened. The file showed one character one cell, not one word one cell. [result](https://imgur.com/a/ALUd756)

I thought that the problem is 'for loop' impacting but have no idea to fix it.
Could you give me some suggestions? I would appreciate it.

I've tried to use another variable to store the data and put it in the 'writerows' function but the result remain the same.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://delicious-fruit.com/ratings/full.php?q=ALL').text
soup= BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

with open ('cms_scrape.csv', 'w', errors='ignore') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    table = soup.find('tbody')
    table_rows  = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        writer.writerows([td[0].text, td[1].text, td[2].text, td[3].text])
csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using writerows which will write multiple rows if you want to write the list in single row you need to use writerow see below example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://delicious-fruit.com/ratings/full.php?q=ALL').text
soup= BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

with open ('d:\\cms_scrape.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    table = soup.find('tbody')
    table_rows  = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        try:
            texts = [str(td1.text).strip() for td1 in td]
            writer.writerow(texts)
        except Exception as e:
            print "error while writing this row %s"%td
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Now, I get it.  The difference between 'writerows' and 'writerow'. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: please check updated code there are some errors due to non ascii characters in the response table